# New statement renders variable outside the scope

Tags: python, scope

Why does the `t2_out` disappear in python 3, being not defined?

```
def returnTempOppositeFlow2(self, t1_in, t2_out, t2_in, m2 ):
    def tosolve(z):       
        t2_out = max(t2_out,t2_in+1.0)
```

Comment: Are you asking why the local variable t2_out in nested function tosolve is not viewable from either function returnTempOppositeFlow2 nor the global scope?

Comment: `t2_out` is a local variable inside the nested `tosolve()` function (which itself is local to the `returnTempOppositeFlow2()` function). Get the idea?

Comment: no, I'm asking why the variable usage throws an error in the nested function tosolve.

Comment: solved- it is not possible to assign the variable in the tosolve function- that might be part of the requirements for fsolve using tosolve().